# Function that tests if DIV is showing only works the second time

Tags: javascript, html, css

This problem is so specific I am not sure any search would find a similar answer, so I am asking as though it is a new problem.

The expected behavior:

- Click button 'mySol' makes div My solution visible
- Click button 'YASS' makes div My solution hidden and div YASS solution visible
- Click button 'Tak' makes div YASS solution hidden and div Takaken solution visible

This works as expected, only after the first time you click all three buttons. The first time through does the following (and is repeatable by refreshing the page):

Click button 'mySol' makes div My solution visible
Click button 'YASS' leaves div My solution visible and makes div YASS solution visible
Click button 'Tak' leaves divs My solution and YASS solution visible and makes div Takaken solution visible
Click button 'mySol' leaves divs YASS solution and Takaken solution visible and makes div My solution hidden
Click button 'YASS' leaves div Takaken solution visible and makes div YASS solution hidden
Click button 'Tak' makes div Takaken solution hidden

These can be done in any order with the same result. After the last div is hidden again the function works properly and one div is visible at a time. I do not understand what is causing this problem, and need some help correcting it.

Any help is appreciated.

Here is the code:

```js
      function visInvis(id) {
        var a = document.getElementById('mySol');
        var b = document.getElementById('YASS');
        var c = document.getElementById('Tak');
        var e = document.getElementById(id);
        if(e == a && e.style.display == 'none') {
          b.style.display = 'none';
          c.style.display = 'none';
        }
        if(e == b && e.style.display == 'none') {
          a.style.display = 'none';
          c.style.display = 'none';
        }
        if(e == c && e.style.display == 'none') {
          a.style.display = 'none';
          b.style.display = 'none';
        }
        if(e.style.display == 'block')
          e.style.display = 'none';
        else
          e.style.display = 'block';
      }
```

```css
      #mySol { display: none; }
      #YASS { display: none; }
      #Tak { display: none; }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<HTML>
  <HEAD>
    <TITLE>Sample Solution Page</TITLE>
  </HEAD>
  <BODY>
    <TABLE align="left" valign="top" width="16%">
      <TR><TH align="left" colspan="2">Puzzle Name</TH></TR>
      <TR><TD>Width:</TD><TH width="50%">0</TH></TR>
      <TR><TD>Height:</TD><TH width="50%">0</TH></TR>
      <TR><TD>Boxes/Goals:</TD><TH width="50%">0</TH></TR>
      <TR><TD colspan="2"><INPUT type="button" style="font-weight: bold;" onClick="visInvis('mySol');" value="My Solution"></TD></TR>
      <TR><TD>Moves/Pushes:</TD><TH width="50%">0/0</TH></TR>
      <TR><TD colspan="2"><INPUT type="button" style="font-weight: bold;" onClick="visInvis('YASS');" value="YASS Solution"></TD></TR>
      <TR><TD>Moves/Pushes:</TD><TH width="50%">0/0</TH></TR>
      <TR><TD colspan="2"><INPUT type="button" style="font-weight: bold;" onClick="visInvis('Tak');" value="Takaken Solution"></TD></TR>
      <TR><TD>Moves/Pushes:</TD><TH width="50%">0/0</TH></TR>
    </TABLE>
    <TABLE align="right" valign="top" border="1" width="65%" height="600" cellspacing=0>
      <CAPTION align="top"><B>Solution</B></CAPTION>
      <TR><TD valign="top">
        <DIV id=mySol>My Solution</DIV>
        <DIV id=YASS>YASS Solution</DIV>
        <DIV id=Tak>Takaken Solution</DIV>
      </TD></TR>
    </TABLE>
  </BODY>
</HTML>
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`e.style.display` only contains styles that are set with inline `style="display: xxx"` attributes, not styles that are inherited from CSS rules. That's why your code doesn't work the first time.

Use `getComputedStyle(e).getPropertyValue('display')`.

```js
function visInvis(id) {
  var a = document.getElementById('mySol');
  var b = document.getElementById('YASS');
  var c = document.getElementById('Tak');
  var e = document.getElementById(id);
  var eStyle = getComputedStyle(e).getPropertyValue('display');
  if (eStyle == 'none') {
    if (e == a) {
      b.style.display = 'none';
      c.style.display = 'none';
    } else if (e == b) {
      a.style.display = 'none';
      c.style.display = 'none';
    } else if (e == c) {
      a.style.display = 'none';
      b.style.display = 'none';
    }
    e.style.display = 'block';
  } else {
    e.style.display = 'none';
  }
}
```

```css
#mySol {
  display: none;
}
#YASS {
  display: none;
}
#Tak {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<HTML>

<HEAD>
  <TITLE>Sample Solution Page</TITLE>
</HEAD>

<BODY>
  <TABLE align="left" valign="top" width="16%">
    <TR>
      <TH align="left" colspan="2">Puzzle Name</TH>
    </TR>
    <TR>
      <TD>Width:</TD>
      <TH width="50%">0</TH>
    </TR>
    <TR>
      <TD>Height:</TD>
      <TH width="50%">0</TH>
    </TR>
    <TR>
      <TD>Boxes/Goals:</TD>
      <TH width="50%">0</TH>
    </TR>
    <TR>
      <TD colspan="2">
        <INPUT type="button" style="font-weight: bold;" onClick="visInvis('mySol');" value="My Solution">
      </TD>
    </TR>
    <TR>
      <TD>Moves/Pushes:</TD>
      <TH width="50%">0/0</TH>
    </TR>
    <TR>
      <TD colspan="2">
        <INPUT type="button" style="font-weight: bold;" onClick="visInvis('YASS');" value="YASS Solution">
      </TD>
    </TR>
    <TR>
      <TD>Moves/Pushes:</TD>
      <TH width="50%">0/0</TH>
    </TR>
    <TR>
      <TD colspan="2">
        <INPUT type="button" style="font-weight: bold;" onClick="visInvis('Tak');" value="Takaken Solution">
      </TD>
    </TR>
    <TR>
      <TD>Moves/Pushes:</TD>
      <TH width="50%">0/0</TH>
    </TR>
  </TABLE>
  <TABLE align="right" valign="top" border="1" width="65%" height="600" cellspacing=0>
    <CAPTION align="top">
      <B>Solution</B>
    </CAPTION>
    <TR>
      <TD valign="top">
        <DIV id=mySol>My Solution</DIV>
        <DIV id=YASS>YASS Solution</DIV>
        <DIV id=Tak>Takaken Solution</DIV>
      </TD>
    </TR>
  </TABLE>
</BODY>

</HTML>
```

Comment: Do I need to replace all instances of a/b/c/e.style.display with this function?

Comment: and in the if conditions as well as the assignment statements?

Comment: You only need to do it when reading the style, not setting -- it doesn't make sense to set a computed style, it's computed by merging all the CSS with the inline style.

Comment: I replaced the e.style.display in the if condition and it made no difference. Changing the setting versions broke everything, I suppose because it was a get and not a set. Would it make a difference if I set the initial state in the tag with an inline style instead of using a style tag in the head?

Comment: I just told you that it makes no sense to do it in the setting code. Anyway, look at my answer, it works for me.

Comment: That fixed it. I replaced the style tag in the head with the style attribute in each div and it works correctly now. Thanks for the help, Barmar! :)

Answer (score 4):

The following code may be help you.

```
   function visInvis(id) {
       var a = document.getElementById('mySol');
       var b = document.getElementById('YASS');
       var c = document.getElementById('Tak');
       var e = document.getElementById(id);

       var eStyle = getComputedStyle(e).getPropertyValue('display');        

       var display = eStyle == 'none' ? 'block' : 'none';       
       a.style.display = b.style.display = c.style.display = 'none'
       e.style.display = display;
   }
```

Comment: If you click the button for the DIV that's already showing, it's supposed to hide it. Your code doesn't handle that case.

Comment: yes, missed this. Now it will work as expected. Thanks for your code line var eStyle = getComputedStyle(e).getPropertyValue('display');

Answer (score 1):

It seems that the browser does not set the display to `none` but to empty string `''`. Thus the function could be fixed as below:

```js
function visInvis(id) {
  var e = document.getElementById(id);
  var eStyle = e.style.display;
  // all off
  document.getElementById('mySol').style.display = '';
  document.getElementById('YASS').style.display = '';
  document.getElementById('Tak').style.display = '';
  // set style to oposite of the original value
  e.style.display = (eStyle == 'block') ? '' : 'block';
}
```

```css
#mySol {
  display: none;
}
#YASS {
  display: none;
}
#Tak {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<HTML>

<HEAD>
  <TITLE>Sample Solution Page</TITLE>
</HEAD>

<BODY>
  <TABLE align="left" valign="top" width="16%">
    <TR>
      <TH align="left" colspan="2">Puzzle Name</TH>
    </TR>
    <TR>
      <TD>Width:</TD>
      <TH width="50%">0</TH>
    </TR>
    <TR>
      <TD>Height:</TD>
      <TH width="50%">0</TH>
    </TR>
    <TR>
      <TD>Boxes/Goals:</TD>
      <TH width="50%">0</TH>
    </TR>
    <TR>
      <TD colspan="2">
        <INPUT type="button" style="font-weight: bold;" onClick="visInvis('mySol');" value="My Solution">
      </TD>
    </TR>
    <TR>
      <TD>Moves/Pushes:</TD>
      <TH width="50%">0/0</TH>
    </TR>
    <TR>
      <TD colspan="2">
        <INPUT type="button" style="font-weight: bold;" onClick="visInvis('YASS');" value="YASS Solution">
      </TD>
    </TR>
    <TR>
      <TD>Moves/Pushes:</TD>
      <TH width="50%">0/0</TH>
    </TR>
    <TR>
      <TD colspan="2">
        <INPUT type="button" style="font-weight: bold;" onClick="visInvis('Tak');" value="Takaken Solution">
      </TD>
    </TR>
    <TR>
      <TD>Moves/Pushes:</TD>
      <TH width="50%">0/0</TH>
    </TR>
  </TABLE>
  <TABLE align="right" valign="top" border="1" width="65%" height="600" cellspacing=0>
    <CAPTION align="top">
      <B>Solution</B>
    </CAPTION>
    <TR>
      <TD valign="top">
        <DIV id=mySol>My Solution</DIV>
        <DIV id=YASS>YASS Solution</DIV>
        <DIV id=Tak>Takaken Solution</DIV>
      </TD>
    </TR>
  </TABLE>
</BODY>

</HTML>
```

Comment: `e` contains the result of calling `document.getElementById(id)`, so it will be one of the elements in `a`, `b`, or `c`.

Comment: Your answer still suffers from his original problem: you can't use `.style` to get the style inherited from CSS.

Comment: I have checked and it worked fine. See post for explanation.

Comment: Can you turn your answer into a stack snippet to demonstrate that it works?

Comment: I see. It's working because `eStyle` is `undefined` the first time, so `eStyle == 'block'` is false.

Comment: I've just set the debug point in that line and for first time it is empty string`''`